# NestedScrollView inside ViewPager inside NestedScrollView: Innermost NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

So I have a Fragment which uses a CoordinatorLayout with a NestedScrollView inside. Inside that NestedScrollView is a ViewPager. Each item of that ViewPager is a CoordinatorLayout with a NestedScrollView inside.

The behavior I want is that when each item inside the ViewPager is scrolled up and down, my custom BottomBar will disappear and reappear.

When I scroll up and down, however, the BottomBar disappears and reappears, but the content in the innermost ScrollView does not move. This is the problem

Code posted below, any advice would be helpful.

Things I've tried:

1. Calling ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled() on nearly every view in the hierarchy that could scroll.
2. Calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) on the outermost NestedScrollView.

**Main Activity:**
[image]

**Fragment w/ outer NestedScrollView:**
[image]

**Each item in ViewPager:**
[image]

Comment: I've got some similar problems...do you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

set this line in ViewPager it will help you

Comment: Thanks Leone, but each item in the ViewPager is still not scrolling.